# how to run this powershell command without curly braces{}

Tags: powershell, recycle-bin

[image]

```
$objShell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace(0xA)
Remove-Item ($objFolder.items() | select path | where-object { $_.path -like "C:\*" }).path -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```

I would like take only the path with C:\ and delete it from recycle bin. But I want to do it without using {} . as u will know where-object needs curly braces. if there's any other way, kindly let me know.

I use powershell version 4 and I prefer code for lower versions only. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Where-Object path -like "C:\*"` works.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. but I get this error. 
Cannot convert the "path" value of typr 'System.String' to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

Comment: @SivaThilak: S.Dev's tip should work in PSv3+. Your error message suggests that you're running _v2_, not v4.

Comment: Tip for PSv5+ users: `Clear-RecycleBin -Drive C:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125170/45375) directly answers your question by demonstrating simplified `Where-Object` syntax (a PSv3+ feature known as a [*comparison statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)).

However, in your case you can bypass `Where-Object` altogether, and apply the `-like` operator directly to the (transformed) enumeration of items returned by `$objFolder.items()`:

Using **PSv2+** syntax:

```sh
Remove-Item (
   @($objFolder.items() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path) -like 'C:\*'
 ) -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```

Note that the use of `@()` ensures that `-like` acts on an *array*-valued LHS and therefore acts as an element *filter*.

`-ExpandProperty` ensures that `.Path` property *values* are returned rather than custom objects with a `.Path` property.

---

In **PSv3+** you can simplify and speed up the command by using *member-access enumeration*, which means accessing a property at the *collection* level in order to return the collection *elements'* property values:

```sh
Remove-Item (
   @(@($objFolder.items()).Path) -like 'C:\*'
 ) -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```

Note that the inner `@(...)`, around `$objFolder.items()`, is only necessary because `$objFolder` is a *COM* object whose properties don't behave like regular .NET collections in PowerShell; `@(...)` forces enumeration in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell 4.0, `Where-Object` supports parameter-based syntax so you don't need the curly braces.

Since the objects returned by `$RecBin.Items()` already have a `Path` property, you can pipe them directly to `Remove-Item`:

```
$RecBin.Items() |Where-Object Path -like "C:\*" |Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```